# Android 4.4.4 Code - How to switch to the next EditText via Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

sorry about my bad English.

I am currently programming an Android App in Android Studio and i want to "go to the next EditText-Field" via keyboard.

In Some Apps is the Button, on the SoftKeyboard, last key right at the Bottom, the "next" KEy or"login" Key.

How to get this Feature with my Edit-Text's, How to link them?

Thank you

Comment: for FSM sake use google ...

Comment: @Selvin I googled FSM. "Finite state machine"? No, that's weird. Second hit: "Flying spaghetti monster". Aaah, +1 :p

Comment: i was searching a long time, you didnt find anything with switch, how should i know that the other one used move, move is not the right word for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [`android:imeOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) for your `EditText` in your layout's xml file.

You will also have to set the value for `android:singleLine` as `true`.